# Пожалуй, возможно, наверно - синонимы?

Tags: общие-вопросы

В чем разница между словами *пожалуй, возможно, наверно*?

Answer (score 2):

> Если долго, долго, долго,
>
> Если долго по тропинке,
>
> Если долго по дорожке
>
> Топать, ехать и бежать,
>
> То **пожалуй**, то **конечно**,
>
> То **наверно**-верно-верно,
>
> То **возможно**-можно-можно,
>
> Можно в Африку прийти!

В приведённой строфе песни происходит игра с этими очень близкими понятиями, совпадающими в значении  *может быть, вероятно, скорее всего, по всей вероятности, по-видимому, судя по всему* (только *конечно,* как безоговорочное утверждение, выбивается из синонимического ряда).

Но, например, у слова *пожалуй* есть ещё несколько значений, к *предположительности* отношения не имеющих...

Тогда открываем толковый словарь и сравниваем:

**[ПОЖАЛУЙ](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9&all=x)**

**[ВОЗМОЖНО](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE)**

**[НАВЕРНО](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x)**

Слово *наверно(е)* в качестве вводного имеет одно-единственное значение и смыслово ближе к *возможно, вероятно, может быть*.

> Вы используете слово **наверное** или **наверно** (в разговорной
>   речи), если вы не совсем уверены, что то, о чём вы сообщаете, является
>   действительным фактом.

А *пожалуй* мне кажется и стилистически выделяющимся из ряда - относительной редкостью употребления и, пожалуй, книжностью. )))

Answer (score 2):

"**Пожалуй**" всегда выражает *личное* предположение говорящего, основанное на *текущих размышлениях* (напр. предваряет только что возникший вывод из предыдущих рассуждений или из последней информации собеседника). Слово несёт оттенок "предварительности" высказанного мнения, которое ещё предстоит осмыслить. Это может быть высказыванием о намерениях на ближайшее будущее или суждением о состоянии дел в настоящем ("пожалуй, это главное").

"**Наверное**" отличается от "пожалуй" тем, что может относиться не только к будущему и настоящему, а ещё и хорошо сочетается с прошлым ("наверное, это он убил").

"**Возможно**" (в функции вводного слова) выражает предположение, которое может основываться на *любой информации* (не только на личном мнении), включая заранее обдуманную.

Comment: В вопросе стоит "наверно", а у Вас - "наверное". Все-таки это разные слова, нужно сделать оговорку, что они эквивалентны.

Answer (score 1):

Разные по происхождению слова "наверное, возможно, пожалуй" в функции вводных выражений сближаются по значению, обозначая в данном случае предположение (тогда их можно считать синонимами), например : Уже, **наверное**, поздно. Уже, **возможно,** поздно. Уже, **пожалуй**, поздно.

Наиболее близки по значению слова "**наверное и возможно**", хотя степень уверенности у них разная.

**А вот слово "пожалуй" стоит особняком**, и этимология у него не очевидная. Вот интересный материал на эту тему: [Этимология слова "пожалуйста" | globallab.org](https://globallab.org/ru/project/blog_message/ed2757fc-d031-11e3-8076-10bf487ee2aa.html#.WNi8HeChqko)

"Слово "пожалуйста" образовалось очень давно, но в законченном, современном виде пришло в литературную речь уже после Пушкина. С глубокой древности пользовались наши предки исконной формой повелительного наклонения: "А дом **пожалуй** продай!" - **будь добр**. Во множественном числе старую форму можно встретить  и сегодня: "**Пожалуйте** в дом!"

Глагол пожаловать имел много значений - "**пожалеть; помиловать; простить; почтить"**, так что пожалуй включало в себя   множество оттенков, понятных только "с голоса", в устной речи. **В XVIII веке пожалуй стало употребляться и как вводное слово со значением неуверенности ("а дом, пожалуй, продай"**), так что выражение вежливой просьбы должно было измениться".

**И вот современное употребление вводного слова "пожалуй":**

**Я, пожалуй, пойду.** Здесь ещё чувствуется оттенок действия (пожалую/приму решение и пойду, такое "неуверенно-повелительное" наклонение).

**Сейчас, пожалуй, поздно.** А здесь от прежней повелительной формы осталась только  неполная уверенность в правильности оценки.

**Примечание** (наверное и наверно, употребляются обе формы)

НАВЕРНО; НАВЕРНОЕ. I. нареч. Несомненно, верно, точно. Я это знаю н. II. вводн. сл. По всей вероятности. Он, н., опаздывает. Ты, н., знаешь этого писателя.

Comment: В вопросе стоит "наверно", а у Вас - "наверное". Все-таки это разные слова, нужно сделать оговорку, что они эквивалентны.

Comment: Да. в словаре указано, что они эквивалентны в обоих значениях.